# Как с помощью jquery обрезать строку после определенного количества символов и добавить троеточие?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция:

```html
<div class="wd">
<a href="#" class="abc"> Текст неопределённой длинны, например: Она была хороша во всём. А без всего - просто божественна. </a>
</div>
```

Необходимо у всех элементов на странице с классом "abc" после 50 символа обрезать строку и поставить троеточие.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать с помощью скрипта?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте [`.substring()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) или [`.substr()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp).

**UPDATE:**

```js
$(".abc").text(function(i, text) {

  if (text.length >= 50) {
    text = text.substring(0, 50);
    var lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");       // позиция последнего пробела
    text = text.substring(0, lastIndex) + '...'; // обрезаем до последнего слова
  }
  
  $(this).text(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="abc">Текст неопределённой длинны, например: Она была хороша во всём. А без всего - просто божественна.</div>

  <div class="abc">Lorem Ipsum - это текст, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной рыбой для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</div>

  <div class="abc">Тут меньше чем 50 сиволов</div>
</div>
```

[О функции `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

Comment: Изначально наверно не совсем корректно задал вопрос, обновил его, смысл в том что надо найти на странице все элементы с классом "abc" и все их порезать после 50 символов, добавив троеточие, как это сделать с помощью вашего решения, можете по подробнее рассказать?

Comment: Отлично, все работает как и хотелось! Поначалу скрипт из ссылок делал простой текст, но добавил  $(".abc a") и все вообще стало как нужно! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста еще, какие изменения добавить в ваш скрипт, чтобы если у элементов с классом "abc" символов меньше или ровно 50, чтобы троеточие НЕ добавлялось? А то у тех строк где нечего не обрезано тоже троеточее, что как бы нелогично

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас все просто идеально!

Comment: @slava, было бы ещё лучше, когда слова не обрезались. Т.е. в конце не было типа :" при..., Вместо привет...". Позже попробую сделать. Хотя я думаю в Гугле есть что-то подобное

Comment: было бы здорово, если сделаете, будут очень признателен!

Comment: @Slava, добавил. Вроде работает:)

Comment: Да у меня тоже работает, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Можно вообще без JavaScript, если для вёрстки:

```css
p.clip {
  width: 400px; /* Можно ограничить и по длинне */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
  overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем все, что не помещается в область */
  background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
  padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Добавляем многоточие */
}
```

```html
<p class="clip">Магнитное поле ничтожно гасит большой круг небесной сферы, 
в таком случае эксцентриситеты и наклоны орбит возрастают.</p>
```

Comment: Условием было конкретно после определенного кол-ва символов.

Comment: @Cactus обновил, теперь длина примерно 50 символов :)

Comment: :DDDDDD, сойдет!) А если надо, чтобы ширина была в `100px`, но что-бы было 50 слов? Увы, способ не подойдёт..

Comment: @socode у меня текст в нескольких строках и количество строк на разных страницах по разному, поэтому в моем конкретном случае css не помощник.. можно было бы попытаться с помощью  "-webkit-line-clamp"  но во-первых не всеми браузерами поддерживается, во-вторых повторюсь количество строк меняется, так что я думаю тут надежнее скриптом

Comment: @Slava ну в таком случае да :)